# Why I can build and run my Android app, but could not run unit test for some support.v4 and v7 issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm using Android Studio to develop my app, and it used to work well. Until recently I noticed that I could still build and deploy my app, however, when I tried to run some unit tests it will give me some class undefined exception, and after looking at the exception, I noticed that it seems there is some problem with support v4 and support v7. Here is a screenshot of the imports strange behavior.
[image] 
Any solution or idea? I already **removed my caches for AS2.0, 2.3, 3.0 and uninstall and reinstall AS3.1.3 and Invalidate and restart, remove gradle cache, clean build, rebuild.**

Comment: Could you post your current build.gradle?

Comment: @WoogieNoogie people have the same gradle with me don't have the same problem...

Comment: I suppose View testing is only available on androidTestCompile (instrumented) and not the testCompile (unitary)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason yet. But I did get the solution. I switched to an older version of code and synched Gradle, and it works, then I switched to new version of code and synched, and it still works.